# convert a string to json object javascript

Tags: javascript, json, stringify

I know that json.stringify() function converts a json object to json string.

```
json.stringify({x:9})
```

this will return string `"{"x" : 9}"`

But is there a way to convert a simple string into json format?
For example i want this

```
var str = '{x: 9}'
json.stringify(str)  //"{"x" : 9}"
```

Comment: `var str = '{"x": 9}'; var obj= JSON.parse(str)`

Answer (score 3):

With a [proper format](http://json.org/) of string, you can use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

```js
var str = '{"x" : 9}',
    obj = JSON.parse(str);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(obj, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery then you can use $.parseJSON See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

Can also visit [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

First solution using **eval**:

```
const parseRelaxedJSON = (str) => eval('(_ => (' + str + '))()')
JSON.stringify(parseRelaxedJSON('{x: 5}'))
```

`(_ => (' + str + '))()` is a self-executing anonymous function. It is necessary for `eval` to evaluate strings similar to `{x: 5}`. This way `eval` will be evaluating the expression function `(_ => ({x: 5}))()` which if you're not familiar with ES6 syntax is equivalent to:

```
(function() {
  return {x: 5}
})()
```

Second solution: using a proper 'relaxed' JSON parser like **[JSON5](https://github.com/aseemk/json5)**

```
JSON.stringify(JSON5.parse('{x: 2}'))
```

[JSBin](https://jsbin.com/somiwuyera/edit?html,console)